# Is std::istream_iterator<int> trivially copy constuctible?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, trivially-copyable

Why does this program compile on MSVC but not on GCC and Clang? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:4,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:83,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:83,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v%3Cstd::istream_iterator%3Cint%3E%3E)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%234%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:4,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%234)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::istream_iterator<int>>);
```

According to [[istream.iterator.cons]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/istream.iterator.cons#6), the constructor must be trivial. Does it relate to [P0738](https://wg21.link/p0738) which moves the wording from *Effects* to *Remarks*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is a difference in implementation. The gcc library has a copy constructor

```
  istream_iterator(const istream_iterator& __obj)
  : _M_stream(__obj._M_stream), _M_value(__obj._M_value),
    _M_ok(__obj._M_ok)
  { }
```

which is non-trivial.

MSVC does not, and apparently relies on a compiler generated one.

Comment: Does it mean that GCC and Clang are non-conforming? If so, are there any bug reports?

Comment: @cppbest: For there to be bug reports, someone would have to actually *use* the `istream_iterator` types. And on top of that, they'd have to write some code that actually cares about the triviality of this type. So a vanishingly small percentage of a vanishingly small percentage of programmers.

Comment: @cppbest See [LWG3600](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3600). The maintainers of libstdc++ thought that the current requirements is unimplementable without ABI break, so they refused to make such change.